# How to write this JSON properly

Tags: json, strapi

I'm writing a JSON API and the input is like this. How can I type this properly in JSON?
The input is JSON in Strapi API

```json
Category 1:
   {
     Name : x
     Price: y
     Url: z
    }
   {
     Name : a
     Price: b
     Url: c
    }
   {
     Name : d
     Price: e
     Url: f
    }
Category 2:

Another array
```

Still have the issue in mapping :

> still have the issue Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `1`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following structure will work just fine for your use case:

```js
{
  "categories": {
    "Category 1": [
      {
        "Name": "x",
        "Price": "y",
        "Url": "z"
      },
      {
        "Name": "a",
        "Price": "b",
        "Url": "c"
      },
      {
        "Name": "d",
        "Price": "e",
        "Url": "f"
      }
    ],
    "Category 2": [
      {
        "Name": "x",
        "Price": "y",
        "Url": "z"
      },
      {
        "Name": "a",
        "Price": "b",
        "Url": "c"
      },
      {
        "Name": "d",
        "Price": "e",
        "Url": "f"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: still have the issue Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `1`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.